Pruned model size is the same of non-pruned model [PyTorch]
I'm trying to implement model pruning on PyTorch with a ResNet18. Given an instance of ResNet18, I run the following code to load a pre-trained model, prune it and save the pruned model:
def random_unstructured_pruning(pruning_rate: float, device, log_file):
    trained_model=retrieve_file(folder="./models", file_name='trained_model.pth')
    model=ResNet18(num_classes=10, input_channels=1).to(device)
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load(trained_model))
    
    modules_list=filter(lambda x: isinstance(x[1], (nn.Conv2d, nn.Linear, nn.BatchNorm2d)), model.named_modules())
    modules_list = map(lambda x: (x[1], 'weight'), modules_list)
    modules_list=tuple(modules_list)
 
  
    prune.global_unstructured(modules_list, pruning_method=prune.L1Unstructured, amount=0.8)
    for module in modules_list:
        prune.remove(module[0], module[1])
        
        
        
    pruning_rate_str= "{:02d}".format(int(pruning_rate * 10))
    path=f"{model_saving_path}pruned_{pruning_rate_str}.pth"
    # 
    torch.save(model.state_dict(), f"{path}")

In the end of the above function, the .pth file has the same dimension of the file that I load at the beginning while I expect it to be smaller since I'm pruning 80% of the weights.
Can somebody explain me why does it happen? What am I wrong?
Thank you!!
I think that the problem is in the saving part of the function, it seems that I'm saving always the same model that I re-load at the beginning and the pruning is not effective.

maybe look into saving the model in a sparse format

I did but PyTorch doesn't support directly copying data between dense and sparse tensors on CUDA devices. I received this error: '('copy_() between dense and sparse Tensors is not implemented! Found self type = torch.cuda.FloatTensor and src type = torch.cuda.sparse.FloatTensor',)'

The pruning utility in Pytorch acts as a masking wrapper on the layer that receives the pruning. This means you still have access to the original model weights and the network size remains unchanged, if not larger because of the initialization of a mask for each pruned tensor.
If you look at the documentation page for prune.global_unstructured:

Modifies modules in place by:

adding a named buffer called name+'_mask' corresponding to the binary
mask applied to the parameter name by the pruning method.

replacing the parameter name by its pruned version, while the original
(unpruned) parameter is stored in a new parameter named name+'_orig'.



Here is a minimal example to show that the unpruned weights are still accessible:
net = nn.Sequential(OrderedDict(
    f1=nn.Linear(10, 5),
    f2=nn.Linear(5, 1)))

pruned = ((net.f1, 'weight'),)
prune.global_unstructured(pruned, prune.L1Unstructured, amount=0.8)

Then you can access the pruned weights:
>>> net.f1.weight
tensor([[0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, -0.0000, 0.0000],
        [0.0000, 0.3599, 0.0000, -0.0000, 0.4034]])

The original unpruned weight:
>>> net.f1.weight_orig
Parameter containing:
tensor([[ 0.1312,  0.1105,  0.0910, -0.2650,  0.3439],
        [ 0.0412,  0.3599,  0.2040, -0.2672,  0.4034]])

And the pruning mask:
>>> net.f1.weight_mask
tensor([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0., 0., 1.]])


Thank you for the answer and the explanation, everything is more clear now! I still have a doubt: what are the metrics that I can compare to show the efficiency of my pruning strategy? I was thinking about model size but, as you said, it doesn't change with pruning; I also thought about non-zero parameters and they decrease when I apply pruning to my model, but what else? Training time? GPU usage?

Maybe look at the flops, but generally, it's the model size that is important to report for this kind of approach.

I'm sorry but I'm a little bit confused. In the beginning, you told me that the size of the .pth file should not change after pruning, so how can I compute the model size to see the effect of pruning?

Size is often reported in number of parameters, so no need to compare file sizes.

Okay, thank you. One last thing, do you suggest any Python library to estimate the number of FLOPs during training or inference?

I have not used such tools but maybe you can refer to this other thread.
